# set classpath other directory in the hierarchy

Tags: java

there are two directories

C:\a\b
C:\a\c

well iam in say directory

c:\a\b

when i do a set classpath=%cd%

the directory C:\a\b gets assigned to the classpath variable

but i want to assign C:\a\c to classpath

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set classpath to sister directory of the one you are currently in, you can use this:

```
# Say you are in C:\a\b
$ set classpath=%cd%\..\c
```

This will set classpath to folder `c` that is in the parent folder of you current directory (i.e. sister folder).

Comment: Logically `C:\a\b\..\c` and `C:\a\c` are the same. Try putting some classes under `C:\a\c` and see if it actually works. I believe it will.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
  set classpath=C:\a\c
```

?

If you wanted to assign two directories, you could separate them with a semi-colon:

```
  set classpath=C:\a\b;C:\a\c
```

Comment: well actually i don't know the directory structure of the computer that this program will run. It should be automated. The script will always be run inside directory b and i want to make directory c as classpath.